# How can i print %d in c

Tags: c

I want to print like `%d` in C but it's showing some number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`printf("%%d")`, or just `fputs("%d", stdout)`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a `%` you need to have `%%`.

```
printf("%%d");
```

prints

```
%d
```

The `printf` man page says:

```
conversion   
specifier

   %         A '%' is written.  No argument is converted.  The complete  con‐
             version specification is '%%'.
```